# How to rephrase in third person?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, grammaticality, editing

How can I phrase this in the third person? (Maybe one word for the person preforming the task)

You and probably everyone else know it's there but everyone chooses to overlook it because it has been deemed socially unacceptable.

Comment: Your second paragraph sounds like it's describing the *elephant in the room*. I'm not sure what you're after with the first paragraph, which first requests a third person rephrasing, then in brackets requests a single adjective, or possibly a noun. Please clarify.

Comment: The first paragraph is saying what i want done to the elephant in the room paragraph. I cant use 'you' because it is in the second person and for it to be in an academic paragraph is must be in the third person

Comment: You can say "People know ...", "Listeners know ..." or, depending on the broader context, even just the generic "You know ...".

Comment: _You and everyone else_ is already third person, as well as second person. What is the question, anyway?

Answer (score 3):

To rephrase your example sentence with a third-person subject (which I think is what you are asking), replace "you and everyone else" with "everyone," then make the verb agree and elide the second "everyone:"

> Everyone knows it's there but chooses to overlook it because it has been deemed socially unacceptable.

Answer (score -1):

It's 'an elephant in the room', which [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/an-elephant-in-the-room) as

> *(informal)* If you say there is an elephant in the room, you mean that there is an obvious problem or difficult situation that people do not want to talk about.

and which [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/elephant-in-the-room.html) defines as

> An important and obvious topic, which everyone present is aware of, but which isn't discussed, as such discussion is considered to be uncomfortable.

Even though Cambridge says it's 'informal' it's used in newspapers to refer to serious situations. Here are two examples.

*[Al Jazeera](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/briefings/2010/09/20109593458899725.html)* provides a sample usage:

> Sidelining Hamas in any process to craft genuine peace between Israelis and Palestinians is a glaring omission tantamount to ignoring an elephant in the room.

The *[Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/answer-sheet/wp/2016/12/10/teacher-to-trumps-education-pick-lets-address-the-elephant-in-the-room-its-you/)* has the following headline:

> Teacher to Trump’s education pick: Let’s ‘address the elephant in the room.’ It’s you.

[Know Your Phrase](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Elephant-in-the-Room.html) provides two example sentences:

> The only functional toilet in the office was clogged and Darill's coworkers believed he was the one responsible, however, they were too embarrassed to mention it to him. Darill decided to speak up and address the elephant in the room by apologizing and admitting that he did indeed clog the toilet.
>
> There was an elephant in the dining room this evening when my brother sat down at the table with a black eye, but did not say anything about what had happened.